# Importing a Swift project from Linux to Mac

Tags: swift

I used CLion and its Swift plugin to start work on a little Swift project. I uploaded the current status to github and now want to work on that on my mac (I followed this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/swift-plugin-for-clion/). How do i import that project on mac now, though? I have AppCode and XCode installed but cant really get it to work. I used AppCode's "import from github" feature but that leaves me with a project that does show the CMakeLists.txt and Package.swift, but not my Sources/ folder at all. And in XCode i can only start new projects for applications, not a static command line lib without any GUI like this project is supposed to be.

So: How do i import them on mac in AppCode (preferred!) or XCode?

Thanks!

EDIT: Oh an when trying to simply checkout my github repo in AppCode it states "no project file found".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've created a SwiftPM package, since you have a `Sources` directory and a `Package.swift` file. If that is correct, you can create an Xcode project with the following command:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 0):

AppCode needs xcodeproj to open the project, without it you cannot open it in AppCode. But you can use the CLion on Mac.